# Azure Resource Manager | Web App Slots Config | App Service Authentication

Tags: json, azure, web-applications, azure-resource-manager

I successfully deployed my ARM template via ADO last week and realised that i forgot to include App Service Authentication for my Web App slots.

I messed around with the Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config and ran into some errors that i was able to overcome with the help of few individuals on Stack.

However, now that the code should work it is failing but i am not getting any error codes on Azure DevOps when releasing.

It just says;

```
2020-07-02T14:20:19.0820320Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please 
list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2020-07-02T14:20:19.0832558Z ##[error]Details:
2020-07-02T14:20:19.0834149Z ##[error]BadRequest: 
2020-07-02T14:20:19.0835776Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2020-07-02T14:20:19.0837268Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Here is my code:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'),'/staging/auth')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('webAppName')]",
                "[concat(parameters('sqlDatabase'), 'constr')]"
            ],
             "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "runtimeVersion": "~1",
                "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
                "tokenStoreEnabled": true,
                "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
                "defaultProvider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
                "clientId": null,
                "clientSecret": null,
                "clientSecretCertificateThumbprint": null,
                "issuer": null,
                "allowedAudiences": [
                    "https://webapptest1a-staging.azurewebsites.net"
                ],
                "additionalLoginParams": null,
                "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
                "googleClientId": null,
                "googleClientSecret": null,
                "googleOAuthScopes": null,
                "facebookAppId": null,
                "facebookAppSecret": null,
                "facebookOAuthScopes": [
                ""
                ],
                "twitterConsumerKey": null,
                "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
                "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
                "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
                "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": [
                ""
                ]
                }
            },
```

Anything sticking out like a sore thumb?

I released the code without this part in it, and it worked fine, so it is most likely this little section here that is causing an issue, but all the information i believe is correct.

According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites/config-authsettings

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: I've had a look at the resource explorer, and i know that the code is mostly correct, but the fact the error i am getting is not verbose enough is really complicating the matter. I've ran out of ideas 100% :|

Comment: There is no specific error showing up? Which authentication provider you want to use for your App Service Authentication?

Comment: Hello Jogarti.

Basically i want this on my Web App Slots:

a) App Service Authentication ON
b) Login with Azure Active Directory.
c) Token Store ON

These are the 3 things i need on my Web App Slots only. Nothing more. 

When i execute my code, there is literally nothing more i am getting for errors that can give me any sort of guidance

Comment: Check this for slot config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/slots/config

Comment: Yeah i already had a look at that! And also this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/slots/config-authsettings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit i found an answer;

Here is the working code;

What i had previously done was this;

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/staging/auth')]",
```

What it needs to be is this;

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/staging/authsettings')]",
```

The "auth" alone will not match anything, and will give back a bad request. Which is right as nothing under "auth" exists meaning it cannot be matched.

So when you put Auth Settings, it actually works as intended as it matches!

[Here is what i followed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/slots/config-authsettings)

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/staging/authsettings')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('webAppName')]",
                "[concat(parameters('sqlDatabase'), 'constr')]"
            ],
                    "properties": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "runtimeVersion": "1.0.0",
                    "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
                    "tokenStoreEnabled": false,
                    "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": null,
                    "defaultProvider":"AzureActiveDirectory",
                    "clientId": null,
                    "clientSecret": null,
                    "clientSecretCertificateThumbprint": null,
                    "issuer": null,
                    "allowedAudiences": null,
                    "additionalLoginParams": null,
                    "isAadAutoProvisioned": false,
                    "googleClientId": null,
                    "googleClientSecret": null,
                    "googleOAuthScopes": null,
                    "facebookAppId": null,
                    "facebookAppSecret": null,
                    "facebookOAuthScopes": [
                    ""
                    ],
                    "twitterConsumerKey": null,
                    "twitterConsumerSecret": null,
                    "microsoftAccountClientId": null,
                    "microsoftAccountClientSecret": null,
                    "microsoftAccountOAuthScopes": [
                    ""
                    ]
                }
            },
```